# Detecting errors generated by $wpdb->get_results()

Tags: database, wpdb, errors

How do I detect errors when using $wpdb->get_results()?

For example:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM this is not a valid query");
```

The preceding code doesn't generate any exceptions or errors; it simply sets $result to an empty array.  How do we reliably detect errors generated by get_results()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a class variable that stores the last error string - $wpdb->last_error. By the looks of the way $wpdb is coded, if the query succeeds, $wpdb->last_error will be an empty string, if it fails, it will be the error string returned by MySQL. So something like this would do the trick.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM this is not a valid query");
if ($wpdb->last_error) {
  echo 'You done bad! ' . $wpdb->last_error;
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable - I can't look into this right now, but if this works, it would come in handy in the future!  Thanks! :)

Comment: Came back to this on a later assignment - works great! I've put this code into a function; I updated your answer; I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can find is:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM this is not a valid query");
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

Unfortunately, that hardly solves the problem.  I want to handle the error programmatically, not just echo it to the output stream.

Comment: I suppose I could always do something nasty with intercepting the output buffer... :/