# $wpdb->insert() does not insert fields

Tags: wp-insert-post

I need to **insert banner data into** a table wp_rdp_banners. To work with the banner data I insert the *full affiliate link* and also *split* it to save the banner url and banner image location into separated fields.

**Somehow there is no data inserted**. Also get no error reports in debug.log file. When I print_r($POST) all seems okay. Correct amount of fields + data.
**But nothing is insert at all.**

> Does someone of you have an idea what I do wrong or forget in the code below?

```
<a href="https://mobico.nl/telefoon/?tt=26156_1144596_250041_&amp;r=" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://ti.tradetracker.net/?c=26156&amp;m=1144596&amp;a=250041&amp;r=&amp;t=html" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="" /></a>

if(isset($_POST['add_new_banner'])){
global $wpdb;
extract($_POST);
$fulllink = htmlspecialchars($aff_link);

$fulllink = stripslashes($fulllink) ;

preg_match_all('!https?://\S+!', $fulllink, $matches); 

$affUrl =$matches[0][0]; // URL link of the banner
$imgLink =$matches[0][1]; // img link from the banner st

$company_name = get_user_meta($customer_id,'company_name',true);

$wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix.'rdp_banners',
            array(
                'banner_type'   => $banner_type,            
                'customer_id'   => $customer_id,            
                'company_name'  => $company_name,
                'start_date'    => $start_date,
                'end_date'      => $end_date,
                'price'         => $price,
                'aff_link'      => htmlspecialchars($aff_link),
                'aff_customer'  => $aff_customer,                   
                'aff_url'       => $affUrl,
                'aff_target'    => $aff_target,
                'aff_rel'       => $aff_rel,
                'aff_img'       => $imgLink,
                'aff_img_width' => $aff_img_width,
                'aff_img_height'=> $aff_img_height,
                'aff_img_alt'   => $aff_img_alt,
                'banner_link'   => $banner_link,
                'picture'       => $picture     
                ),
             array( '%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
    );              
}
exit( var_dump(  $wpdb->prepare  ) );
```

result = NULL

Comment: Check this topic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141627/detecting-errors-generated-by-wpdb-get-results to see mysql errors. Did your $wpdb declared  globally?

Comment: yes see it at top of the code. Forget to paste it there.

Comment: Have you tried to display wpdb errors?

Comment: How do i do this. Tried this piece : exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) ); but get only string(39) "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_rdp_banners`"

Comment: Try to dump $wpdb->last_error

Comment: I get now: string(0) ""

Comment: Ok, try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110270/126253

Comment: see results above in thread

Comment: I can't understand anything here, sorry. Try to write insert query with $wpdb->prepare to debug it. You can also use SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; in your mysql client

Comment: `extract($_POST);` is extremely dangerous, anybody can overwrite anything in the global namespace here, this is a super critical vulnerability. Don't use `extract`

Comment: Also you never check the return value of `$wpdb->insert` to see what happened, for all you know it's a `WP_Error` object with a message explaining exactly why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Apparently with the new WP update if you try to insert into a VARCHAR column and the column length is less than what you are trying to insert it just won’t work. Prior to this update it will insert it but trim off the excess characters.

Comment: Thanks for your time and idea. Will try and test it. Project was already delivered.